# How do I get a string from my servlet and use it in my ajax function

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have a servlet that contains a string, wherein the latter is a JSON string with multiple entries. Now I want to access this String with ajax through jQuery. Now here if my function:

```
function myFunction() {
    $("#myButton").click(function() {
         $.ajax({ 
             url: // servlet,
             type: "GET",
             dataType : "text",
             success: function() // I want to display the string from the servlet,
             error:  // stuff


    // other code
```

Anyway how can I do this. Also can I place another function in the success part rather than an anonymous function?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to display the string from the servlet,

your [success](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) method has a parameter `data`

```
success: function(data){ alert( data ); }
```

> Also can I place another function in the success part rather than an
>   anonymous function?

```
success: namedFunction, 

function namedFunction(data){ alert(data); }
```

Comment: `namedFunction(data)` will be called/executed when that line of code will be parsed. Function expression need to be passed I guess. `data` will be first argument of the callback function hence no need to pass `data` just in case you are about to write `namedFunction(data)` inside anonymous function..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function expression to be executed on `success` or `error`. First argument for success callback is `response` sent via server.

Try this:

```js
function successGoesHere(response) {
  console.log(response);
}

function errorGoesHere(err) {
  console.log(err);
}

function myFunction() {
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "YOUR_URL",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "text",
      success: successGoesHere,
      error: errorGoesHere
    })
  })
}
```

As you are passing `dataType : "text"` in `ajax config`, response will always be plain text, just in case you are expecting it to be `json`, your response will be `string representation of json` hence you will have to parse it using `JSON.parse(response)` to get `JSON object`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
function getString(url, handleResponse, handleFailure) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, true);
    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {
            if (handleResponse) {
                handleResponse(request.responseText);
            }
        } else {
            if (handleFailure) {
                handleFailure(request.status);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

this just gets a string from URL (No JQuery)

Comment: jQuery is tagged in the question. Any reason to use Vanilla JS ajax syntax over jQuery ?

Comment: No good reason in particular, just an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax request  success : function(resp){
code for parsing json and show parsed json 
// var json = $.parseJSON(data);
}

[You need to look this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367905/use-jquery-ajax-json-response)

Answer (score 0):

```
var callback = function(data, textStatus, xhr)
{
    alert(data + "\t" + textStatus);
}

var testman = function(str, cb) {
    var data = 'Input values';
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '',// servlet
        data: data,
    success: cb
    });
}
testman('Hello, Dear', callback);
```